# How to make a fluid sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a sidebar with this CSS code:

```
.sidebar {
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
border-right: 1px solid #333;
}
```

But the sidebar width doesn't scale when I change the browser width. How can I make the sidebar fluid?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide an example on jsfiddle.com?

http://jsfiddle.net/BQW9F/

Comment: does your sidebar have a parent container?

Comment: Seems to [work](http://jsfiddle.net/tGnCj/embedded/result/).

Comment: why not? it does scale upon browser resize. why it wouldn't? you have given width in percentage

Comment: Could you provide the HTML and any other CSS?

Comment: Your exact code works for me. Is it inside another (fixed-size) container?

Comment: Please determine correct answer!

Answer (score 4):

**Look at the height in body in CSS part.**

Here is a working example for you:

Your HTML:

```
<div id="content"> 
<p>This design uses a defined body height of 100% which allows setting the contained left and 
right divs at 100% height.</p> 
</div> 

<div id="sidebar"> 
<p>This design uses a defined body height which of 100% allows setting the contained left and 
right divs at 100% height.</p> 
</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
body { 
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
width:100%; /* this is the key! */ 
} 

#sidebar { 
position:absolute; 
right:0; 
top:0; 
padding:0; 
width:30%; 
height:100%; /* works only if parent container is assigned a height value */ 
color:#333; 
background:#eaeaea; 
border:1px solid #333; 
} 

#content { margin-right: 200px; }
```

Comment: the OP talks about a fluid width, not height.

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of an odd issue, but it seems its challenging to get the background color to stretch to the bottom of both columns, when using fluid layout.

I included the workaround along with a simple 2 column fluid layout.

Try this- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/S84S7/5/)

```
    html, body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background:silver; 
/* workaround to get the columns to look even, 
change color depending on which column is longer */ 
    }

    #sidebar {
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        padding:0;
        width:30%;
        background:silver;
        word-wrap:break-word;
    }

    #content {
        position:absolute;
        right:0px;
        width:70%;
        word-wrap:break-word;
        background:gray;
    }
```